# Tablet app & Mobile app

Tags: android, android-layout

hi I am developing an android app that support mobile and tablet. I have finished list & details page in both tablet and mobile. But I need to show the creation page, In tablet it should open in popup window and the same thing in phone it should be open as normal activity. how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My requirement is solved from the following articals http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#ActivityAsDialog

Answer (score 0):

You can just approximate if it's a tablet or not by checking the screendimension. If the app uses XLARGE or LARGE display dimensions, it could be a tablet or a "big" phone.

You can get informations about that with something like this:

```
if(getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE 
|| getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE) {
    //doSomething
}
```

You can test which of these ones is the better one for you.

Comment: from your answer, I need to declare two different activity one for popup activity and another for normal activity may i correct?

Comment: You can also request two different activitysizes at the creation of your activity or transmit the information with a bundle or something like this – depends on the goal you want to achieve ;) You can also set different layouts in one activity if the device is a big device or not.